# FIWARE OAuth2 Authentication in Node JS

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, fiware

I'm trying to authenticate users in Fiware from Node JS.
I've created a server code that calls Oauth2 and when running it, it redirect you to fiware page, but when logging in Fiware shows nothing, and then when checking /user_info page it gives access token is null

here is my config.js:
$

```
  var config=require('config');
config.idmURL = 'http://account.lab.fiware.org';
config.client_id = '2456';
config.client_secret = '12466';
config.callbackURL = 'http://localhost/login';

module.exports = config;
```

$
The oauth2.js file is the one from : https://github.com/ging/oauth2-example-client/blob/master/oauth2.js

The code that calls Oauth2 is the following:
$

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');
var OAuth2 = require('./oauth2').OAuth2;
var config = require('./config');
var cookieparser= require('cookie-parser');
var expresssession= require('express-session');


var app = express();
app.use(cookieparser());
app.use(expresssession({
    secret: "257a57604cb5037dcfc2d42127e1104cb705f92344ff74aabadf14d0248cbe266d3e7d567bf7068645668add108a459b5d9af1917ddc6a47cae82a7a9798ae9d"
}));

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 13299);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

//code I got from  http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WebMatrixAndNodejsTheEasiestWayToGetStartedWithNodeOnWindows.aspx
/*module.exports = function (app)
{
    app.get('/', function (req, res)
    {
        res.render('index',
        {
            message: 'Welcome to my site!'
        });
    });
    app.get('/about', function (req, res)
    {
        res.render('about');
    });
}*/
app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

//app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});


// .....
// Creates oauth library object with the config data
var oa = new OAuth2(config.client_id,
                    config.client_secret,
                    config.idmURL,
                    '/oauth2/authorize',
                    '/oauth2/token',
                    config.callbackURL);

// Handles requests to the main page
app.get('/', function (req, res)
{

    // If auth_token is not stored in a session cookie it sends a button to redirect to IDM authentication portal 
    if (!req.session.access_token)
    {
        res.send("Oauth2 IDM Demo.<br><br><button onclick='window.location.href=\"/auth\"'>Log in with FI-WARE Account</button>");

        // If auth_token is stored in a session cookie it sends a button to get user info
    } else
    {
        res.send("gghhhhhhhhhhhh");
        res.send("Successfully authenticated. <br><br> Your oauth access_token: " + /*req.session.access_token + */"<br><br><button onclick='window.location.href=\"/user_info\"'>Get my user info</button>");
    }
});

// Handles requests from IDM with the access code
app.get('/login', function (req, res)
{

    res.end(req.query.code + "Hello Http, This is the server responding ............");

    // Using the access code goes again to the IDM to obtain the access_token
    oa.getOAuthAccessToken(req.query.code, function (e, results)
    {

        // Stores the access_token in a session cookie
        req.session.access_token = results.access_token;
        res.end("Hello Http, This is the server responding");
        res.send("from inside /login code");
        res.redirect('/');

    });
});

// Redirection to IDM authentication portal
app.get('/auth', function (req, res)
{
    var path = oa.getAuthorizeUrl();
    res.redirect(path);
});


// Ask IDM for user info
app.get('/user_info', function (req, res)
{
    var url = config.idmURL + '/user/';
    if (req.session.access_token == null)
    {
        res.send("access token is null");
    }
    // Using the access token asks the IDM for the user info
    oa.get(url, req.session.access_token, function (e, response)
    {
        //res.end("hiiiiiiiiiiii5555444");
        var user = JSON.parse(response);
        res.send("Welcome " + user.displayName + "<br> Your email address is " + user.email + "<br><br><button onclick='window.location.href=\"/logout\"'>Log out</button>");
    });
});

// Handles logout requests to remove access_token from the session cookie
app.get('/logout', function(req, res){

    req.session.access_token = undefined;
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

$

when running it keeps giving access_token is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
config.callbackURL = 'http://http://192.168.1.41/:10251/login';
```

Callback URL is wrong.

EDIT:
After edit, your callback is still wrong:

```
config.callbackURL = 'http://localhost/login';
```

The IdM is supposed to be able to call the callback URL. How will it do it if it is in localhost?

Comment: thanks for the reply: I tried both:
config.callbackURL = 'http://192.168.1.41:app_port/login'; or 
config.callbackURL = 'http://public_ip:router_port/login';
 but still doesn't work and gives me invalid authorization request

Comment: Now I am getting : "We're sorry, but something went wrong." after logging in

Comment: The final url that gets called is: 
https://account.lab.fiware.org/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=2456&state=xyz&redirect_uri=213.123.216.45:10251//login
Any idea?

Comment: I would be really interested to know your opinion @LeandroGuillen

Comment: Like @GuilleJ said, it could be that the ports where your app is listening are not reachable, whether they are in a local machine or in a cloud environment (for example) with a public IP.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you must configure your callback as showed previously:

`config.callbackURL = 'public_ip:app_port/login'`

And you should check your VM security group to ensure your app_port is open (If you are deploying the server into the cloud) otherwise, if you are in a local machine, check your router ports to be accesible from outside.

I see you are setting up this port:
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 13299);